# Basic Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace every instance of a single letter followed by a = sign followed by a letter with spaces between = and the letters.  So `h=e` would be replaced with `h = e`.  This is what I have right now:

```
definition = 'h=e'
definition = re.sub(r"\w=\w", r"\w\s=\s\w", definition)
```

But that yields `\w\s=\s\w` rather than `h = e`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you mean space in the replacement, use space, not a regex meaning "any type of whitespace"

Comment: The replacement in re.sub explicitly allows backreferences that refer to capture groups in the original match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement shouldn't be another regular expression, it should be an ordinary string (or a function).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

> ```
> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
> ```
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. **repl can be a string or a function**

For example:

```
definition = 'h=e'
definition = re.sub(r"(\w)=(\w)", "\g<1> = \g<2>", definition)
print(definition)
```

But it would be easier to use a word boundary here:

```
definition = 'h=e'
definition = re.sub(r"\b=\b", " = ", definition)
print(definition)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid consuming the part of the string you don't want to replace, but still assert that the parts around it match something by using lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\w)=(?=\w)", " = ", "h=e")
'h = e'
```

You can put whatever pattern in these. e.g.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=x)=(?=y)", " = ", "y=z z=q y=x x=y a=b")
'y=z z=q y=x x = y a=b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
re.sub(r"\w=\w", r"\w\s=\s\w", definition)
```

to

```
re.sub(r'(\w)=(\w)', r"\g<1> = \g<2>", definition)
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) specifically mention that

> Unknown escapes such as `\&` are left alone.

A literal space in the replacement is all you need. `\s` is meaningless there. You also need to add groups to your expression to capture the part of the substitution that you *don't* want to replace:

> Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

Your substitution should look something like this then:

```
definition = re.sub(r"(\w)=(\w)", r"\1 = \2", definition)
```